# Can I manage SignalR 'conversations' in a JMeter performance test?

Tags: jmeter, signalr

I am using JMeter to try and test a web application that also uses SignalR.

I found some good information here, http://www.ronaldrosier.net/category/signalr

I have tried one or two approaches without any success but I think I have a reasonably good handle on the conversations.

However, my rather simplistic question is whether it is actually possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible as long as JMeter allows you to extract values from the response of one request and use it as parameters to further requests. This is because SignalR clients first send a negotiate request to which the server replies with a unique, server-signed cursor token, which must then be present in the querystring of all further requests, including send and receive operations. These connection tokens cannot be generated on the client.

SignalR actually has a load generation tool available called Crank. It's available as source in the GitHub repository for SignalR at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Crank

Comment: Been able to go a bit further but still not managing to properly 'manage' a conversation. Our app creates a 'project', SignalR is used to message the progress of this activity. I can make an initial contact - /filestate/negotiate?_ - sent with a timestamp - and get this reply {"Url":"/filestate","ConnectionId":"98685ccd-cf38-4e09-bb82-ec080ac3bdc3","TryWebSockets":false,"WebSocketServerUrl":null,"ProtocolVersion":"1.0"} - after that however every request I make results in a timeout.